# ImportError: No module named pathlib Windows OS and Python version 3.8

Tags: django, pathlib, pyhook

Hi im trying to run a venv for my project. Everythin goes well install requirments and creating a my venv. The problem is that when i try to make a manage.py migrate i get this error. Ive looked everywhere and i got python version 3.8 installed. Pathlib is part of the package from python 3.4.

I use Windows and python 3.8 with Django version 3.0.12- My project is based on a cockiecutter and i dont want to update to the latest version om django.

Does anone know what the problem is and how it can be solved?

```
 manage.py migrate
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Dev\Fooders\fooders\manage.py", line 4, in <module>
 from pathlib import Path
 ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
python manage.py migrate

# or if it does not work

python3 manage.py migrate
```